# Understanding the code break and label Java

Tags: java, label, break

Hello I'm new to Java and I'm self learning so i have (maybe) a stu... question. I need your help with understanding this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x, y;

for(x = 0; x < 5; x++) 
stop2:  {   
    for(y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
        if(y == 2) break stop2;
        System.out.println("Varaiables x and y: " + x + " " + y);
```

I don't understand why when I run the code I get:

0 0

0 1

1 0

1 1

2 0

2 1

3 0

3 1

4 0

4 1

Why in second row it starts with x = 0 and only in third it is x = 1?
Thank you in advance for your time. :D

Comment: Use a debugger or take a piece of paper and "run" the code in your head step by step writing down what you think happens. Then if there is still something unclear ask about that specific detail. Simply dumping a piece of code and asking us to explain it isn't what this site is for.

Comment: what do you thing you should get?

Comment: Sorry I allready edited it.

Answer (score 0):

The code snapshot contains 2 nested *for* loops: outer and inner.
For each value of outer *for* loop, the entire inner *for* loop shall execute as per nesting.

The inner *for* loop is labeled as 'stop2'.

It starts with x=0, y=0 which get printed.
Thereafter, y gets incremented as per inner *for* loop; and it prints x=0, y=1.

when y is incremented further i.e. y=2, the break statement moves the control out of inner *for* loop (where the print is skipped) and control comes to outer *for* loop where x is incremented to 1.

The same sequence, as with x=0, is now repeated, and likewise keep getting printed.

Comment: Oh i see so the inner for loop goes on until y = 2 and then when it breaks, the outer loop increments to x = 1 Now I know why x stays 0 twice. Then the program continues to the inner loop again and y gets again asigned 0? Shouldn't y stay 2 and increment to 3? Is it that when it breaks than it resets like it was not called and thats why y is asigned 0?

Answer (score 0):

Because here:

```
if(y == 2) break stop2;
```

Your code exit on second loop (y == 2) and  go first loop (x++).